# Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down keyboard shortcut is prevented, how to find what's causing it?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

In my code editor, I am used to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd> keyboard shortcut. However, on my new notebook, this shortcut doesn't even arrive to the application (there is a test area for keyboard shortcuts and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd> simply does nothing while the other combinations are easily detected).

I thought it might have something to do with the Intel GPU driver which by default maps this shortcut to making the screen upside down but the problem persists even after I disabled the hotkeys there. I confirmed with my colleague that with these hotkeys disabled, it should work normal. On my PC, though, it doesn't.

How can I find the offending application?

Comment: How?  Trial and Error.  Boot into a minimal configuration and one by one allow a program that normally starts up to be loaded.

Comment: You could use AutoHotKey to hopefully override what ever is doing the overriding...  :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using the [ActiveHotkeys](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=18189.0) program to check whether the keys are registered as global hotkeys or not, and the one-by-one start closing down applications on my system and re-checking after each application closed until I see the hotkeys deregistered. This includes system tray applications and other background programs.

(Note, you have to click **Test Active Hotkeys** again each time you re-check, since it doesn't auto-refresh)

Comment: Is there something similar for 64bit Windows? I unfortunately can't use ActiveHotkeys but it looks like a really useful tool.

Comment: @Borek I have it up on my 64-bit system right now. I just opened the portable version in the .zip file, for what it's worth.

Comment: Solved using the similar utility http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/. BTW, it was really the Intel driver causing, specifically the `igfxHK Module` process. Many thanks.

Comment: @Borek - When I run the utility you linked to, it says that igfxHK.exe is reserving the hotkey. How do I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I used the application Borek suggested in a comment... the Windows Hotkey Explorer which you can download from hkcmdr.anymania.com.

That revealed that the shortcut was being hijacked by an Intel program called igfxHK.exe. It's a graphics program or something, but it has a bug that makes it so that whether you tell it to enable hot keys or disable them, it registers them either way.

To get around the bug, the best thing you can do, I think, is just reassign the hotkeys to a key combination you will never need/use.

1. Right click your desktop and pick `Graphics Properties...`
2. Pick Options and Support
3. Enable hotkeys if it says they're disabled.
4. Change Rotate to 0 Degrees and Rotate to 180 Degrees. I went with Ctrl Shift Fn11 and Ctrl Shift Fn12 - that's an obscure keystroke with 4 keys that I will never want to actually hit.
5. Disable hotkeys.
6. Apply

Refresh in the Windows Hotkey Explorer and it should now show that igfxHK.exe has registered those other stupid hotkeys, not the userful ones used by your editor.